# Phonegap SQLite Transaction Crash on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, crash, cordova

I need to insert a lot of data into a SQLite database. I use transactions for it. There is unfortunatly no chance I can fill the tables without these transactions. My code works like this:

```
database.transaction(function(transaction) {
    for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        sql = "INSERT INTO test (fielda, fieldb, fieldc) VALUES (111, 1, 23.53)";
        transaction.executeSql(sql, function(result) {

        });
    }
}, function() {
    database.transaction(function(transaction) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            sql = "INSERT INTO test (fielda, fieldb, fieldc) VALUES (111, 1, 23.53)";

            transaction.executeSql(sql, function(result) {

            });
        }
    }, function() {
               .................and so on..............
        alert("done");
    }, function(error) {
        alert("error");
    });
}, function(error) {
    alert("error");
});
```

It works fast and easy on my iPad 2 but crashes just as fast on my Galaxy Tab 3. It seems that the number of successive transactions doesn't matter but the number of inserts they have to perform altogether. Always around the 900th entry it crashes. That means it crashes in the 4th transaction with loops of i < 300 but needs 10 transactions with loops of i < 100 to crash.

I even tried calling 3 transactions with one button click, then waited for over ten minutes and calling the 4th transactions by clicking on another button. It still crashes.

There are happening other strange things as well:
When I call "DELETE FROM test" at some point before calling the transactions the app throws the error message "Cannot perform this operation because there is no current transaction." just before it crashes then during the transaction. But only then.

I already played around with every PRAGMA there is, like page_size, journal_mode, etc. It doesn't change a thing.

Comment: I faced a similar issue and it comes out to be an issue with cursor handling in Java file. In Java the code was trying to close the cursor when it was unavailable. Post the complete Java error you are receiving on crash.